# MS Access Underscore in Value not able to exclude

Tags: underscore.js

I am using MS Access 2010 and I have below example query where I am trying to exclude all value in USER_NAME filed which starts with FF and it is not working for any record where i have values FF_ABC, FF_XYZ etc. How do I exclude such values where _ is included in value ?

SELECT SYS_USERS.USER_NAME
FROM SYS_USERS
WHERE (((SYS_USERS.USER_NAME) Not Like 'FF%'))
ORDER BY SYS_USERS.USER_NAME;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your issue is that youre using the wrong wildcard. Access uses * as a LIKE wildcard operator.

Also, WHERE INSTR(1, colunName, "_")=0 should suffice as well